# KeyError when upgrading custom model in odoo 12

Tags: python, keyerror, odoo-12

When I Install a custom model(apps) in odoo 12 There are no errors and I can use this model. But when I change for example a field width in the formview I receive an KeyError like:

> File "C:\Bitnami\odoo-12\apps\odoo\Lib\site-packages\odoo-12.0.post20200815-py3.7.egg\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 177, in **getitem** return self.models [model_name]
> **KeyError**: 'qualities'

Whatever I change in formview, I'll still get the same error.

Python source:

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api, _
from odoo.tools import ustr
import math

# Setup test module-1
# Skip _name = when inherit product_template

class Calc(models.Model):
    _name = 'calc'
    _description = 'Module t.b.v. calculation-functions'

    qualities_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="qualities", string="Karton kwaliteit")
    qualities_dikte = fields.Float(string="Golf dikte", related='qualities_id.golfdikte', readonly=True)
    qualities_ref = fields.Char(string="Reference", related='qualities_id.reference', readonly=True)
```

XML source (part):

```xml
<div>
  <field name="qualities_id"    class="oe_inline" />
  <field name="qualities_dikte" class="oe_inline" />
  <field name="qualities_ref"   class="oe_inline" />
</div>
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem at this line:

```
qualities_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="qualities", string="Karton kwaliteit")
```

When we declare any field with Many2one datatype, Odoo looks for the destination database table. In your case, table names are qualities.

Following way we can resolve it:

- If the qualities table doesn't exist, Change data type if you don't have any qualities table.
- If a qualities table exists, Check .py import file sequence or make sure qualities code executes before you use it in any other file or same file.